# Fastreport hyperlink external URL

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I'm trying to create a hyperlink (external URL) in a `TfrxMemoView` object but the link redirects me to a local directory, what's happening? Am I doing something wrong or is it some limitation of the tool?

In the Hyperlink Editor I add the basic link in the variable `link_application` (https://myapplication.host.com/rest/mywebservice/) together with a variable field of the report, so that I create a link to a webservice.

[image]

At the end, the link redirects me to the following location:

> file:///C:/users/myUser/Desktop/'https://myapplication.host.com/rest/mywebservice/354310'

What it should be:

> https://myapplication.host.com/rest/mywebservice/354310

Comment: Does it work as expected if you enter the full URL in the first field?

Comment: Yes, putting it as a specify URL works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem was a bug from version **5.4.6** of Fast Report VCL 5, which was the version I was using.

In the latest version (**5.6.18**) the bug has already been fixed.